# Modify "get_cart_contents_count()" to count only specific product IDs in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I have 3 ticket products in WooCommerce and want to add a name field per ticket product purchased - so if a customer buys three tickets 3 name fields are displayed to fill out in the checkout.

The code below works:

```php
// Custom WooCommerce Checkout Fields based on Quantity
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'person_details' );

function person_details($checkout) {

    global $woocommerce;

    $count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    $i = 1;

    for($k=2; $k<= $count; $k++) {
        $i++;

        print ('<h3>Please enter details of attendee '.$i.'</h3>');

        woocommerce_form_field( 'cstm_full_name'.$i, array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Full name'),
            'placeholder'   => __('Enter full name'),
            ),
        $checkout->get_value( 'cstm_full_name'.$i ));

        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
    }
}
```

But this includes all products added to cart - how can I target specific Product IDs to be only be part of the cart count?

```php
$count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative and most recommended way, you can use [WC_Cart::get_cart_item_quantities()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cartget_cart_item_quantities/) and [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) in your callback function to get the cart item quantity from specific product IDs in cart

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_order_notes( $checkout ) {
    // True
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Specific product IDs
        $product_ids = array( 30, 823, 53, 57 );

        // Initialize
        $count = 0;

        // Loop trough cart items quantities
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_item_quantities() as $product_id => $cart_item_quantity ) {
            // Checks if a value exists in an array
            if ( in_array( $product_id, $product_ids ) ) {
                $count += $cart_item_quantity;
            }
        }

        // Result
        echo '<p style="color: red; font-size: 25px;">Count = ' . $count . '</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'action_woocommerce_before_order_notes', 10, 1 );
```

---

**OR**

You could use the `woocommerce_cart_contents_count` filter hook,
which allows you to customize the `get_cart_contents_count()` function to your needs:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_contents_count( $array_sum ) {
    // True
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Specific product IDs
        $product_ids = array( 30, 823, 53, 57 );

        // Loop trough cart items quantities
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart_item_quantities() as $product_id => $cart_item_quantity ) {
            // Checks if a value NOT exists in an array
            if ( ! in_array( $product_id, $product_ids ) ) {
                $array_sum -= $cart_item_quantity;
            }
        }
    }

    return $array_sum;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_contents_count', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_contents_count', 10, 1 );

function action_woocommerce_before_order_notes( $checkout ) {
    // True
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Get number of items in the cart.
        $count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

        // Result
        echo '<p style="color: red; font-size: 25px;">Count = ' . $count . '</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'action_woocommerce_before_order_notes', 10, 1 );
```

**Note:** although the advantage here is that you can continue to use the `get_cart_contents_count()` function in this way, the disadvantage is that this function would also display the modified result when used for other purposes

Comment: Went with the first way, works well!